# MongoDB ATLAS to on-premise migration

Tags: mongodb, migration

How can we migrate data from MongoDB ATLAS to on-premise with minimal downtime? We can migrate from on-premise to ATLAS using mongomirror. Is there any similar tool to migrate date from MongoDB ATLAS to on-premise

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: have you tried using mongomirror in the other direction?

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool for migrating data from the MongoDB atlas to the on-premise deployment.

You can try the following options but that require downtime:
1. mongodump and mongorestore.
2. you can download the backup if it is enabled in your atlas account to your own machine and then you can restore it.

What is your datasize anyways ?